# Even dimensional Lens spaces

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

I am studying on my own Lens spaces from the algebraic topology viewpoint. I read about them on Hatcher's book as you can deduce from some of  my previous questions:

[cw-construction-of-lens-spaces-hatcher](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748028/cw-construction-of-lens-spaces-hatcher)

[computing-boundary-homomorphisms-in-cellular-chain-complex-of-lens-spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1748811/computing-boundary-homomorphisms-in-cellular-chain-complex-of-lens-spaces)

I have been thinking...is it possible to construct even dimensional Lens spaces?

I have looked in Google but I haven't found anything. So I suspect that maybe the action doesn't work fine on even dimensional spheres. Any reference to look for it? or any argument in one or the other direction?

P:D: Just to remember, this is the definition of Lens space that I am using:

[image: ht]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For even dimensional spheres, we have the following theorem.

Suppose:  Suppose $\pi:S^{2n}\rightarrow L$ is a covering map.  Then either $\pi$ is a diffeomorphism or is a $2$-fold covering and $L$ is non-orientable.  In particular, $L$ has fundamental group either trivial or $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.

Proof:  Let $G = \pi_1(L)$ and pick $g\in G$.  Consider the induced action of $G$ on $S^{2n}$ as the Deck group.

Then $g:S^{2n}\rightarrow S^{2n}$ is a homeomorphism.  Assume initially that this map is orientation preserving.  Then it has degree $1$ and thus, according to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1489715/if-fx-neq-gx-for-every-x-%E2%88%88-s-n-then-g-is-homotopic-to-a-f), because $g$ is *not* homotopic to the antipodal map (because $2n$ is even), $g$ must have a fixed point.  But an element of the Deck group which fixes a point must be the identity, so $g = e\in G$.

This shows that the identity is the only orientation preserving element of $G$.  What about orientation reversing elements?  Well, if $h_1,h_2\in G$ both reverse orientation, then $h_1h_2^{-1}$ preserves orientation, so $h_1h_2^{-1} = e$, so $h_1 = h_2$.  Thus, if there is an orientation reversing element of $G$, there is only one.

Thus, $G$ consists of $1$ or $2$ elements, so $G = \{e\}$ or $G=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$.